# Configure Mail Server in AWS ec2 amazon ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, configure, mail-server

I want to configure MailServer in AWS ec2 amazon ubuntu server 14.04 LTS to receive mails on account.
Can any one provide the steps or links to me for it ??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to receive emails or send email? If you are looking for an Email server, there are several open source Mail servers are available like Qmail , Zimbra etc. You can google and try that.

Comment: I want to receive emails.